# Return video with Javax Rest Api

Tags: java, rest, media

I'm working on android app and back-end server Rest API part.
I'm at the point where i need to return some video files from the server back to my android device. How can i do that?
I looked up jersey documantation https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/jax-rs.html#d4e142
and  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#restjersey_annotations
but din't have any luck figuring this out..

For images i've been using the

```
 @Produces(image/jpg)
```

Is there a similar way i can do to share mpeg4 or any other video files?
What would be the best approach there?

Comment: The mime type for mp4 is 'video/mp4'.

Comment: So you are saying that this would work?
@Produces( 'video/mp4')

Comment: I am not certain, which is why I am just commenting and not giving this as an answer. I am making a suggestion of something to try. And, yes, @Produces( video/mp4)  looks like it might work.

Comment: Thank you! i'll try it and will let you know how it goes in a few!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As android client can stream the video content, try something like this

```
@GET
@Path("video")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response video() {
    File file = new File("C:/Data/video.mp4");
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I am unable to seek the video using this approach.
How to make the video seekable?

Comment: Seeking? https://tutorial-academy.com/rest-jersey2-resume-video-streaming